# Is there a distinction between a "specific" ("nominated") real number and an "anonymous" real number?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability

> The Axiom of Choice: If $a$ is a class of non-empty sets $x,$ there exists a function $f$ such that $f\left(x\right)\in{x}$ for all $x\in{a}.$

https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke

The reason this question is relevant to the axiom of choice is that the axiom provides us with a function that **chooses** an element form any set of real numbers, but the function **does not specify** the chosen element.

I have added the adjective *nominated* as a synonym for *specified*.  That is, *specifying* may also be considered *naming*.  I have given an example of a named real number which is not an element of the countably infinite set of rational numbers.  It is asserted that there are uncountably meany such real numbers.

My understanding of the theory of formal systems tells me that, since any formal system must be specified using some necessarily finite vocabulary,  there are at most a countably infinite number of producible instructions. Since an algorithm is a set of instructions, there exist at most a countably infinite number of algorithms of any formal system.

It appears to me that any specified real number must correspond with at least one algorithm for accurately determining, to an arbitrary precision, its value relative to the rational numbers.  For example, the specific number $\pi$ can be approximated by a number of different methods, all of which begin with an initial condition stated in a finite number of symbols.  The algorithm for producing each subsequent refinement of the current approximation must also be stated in a finite number of symbols.

We thereby *specify* a real number, the value of which cannot be precisely determined in a finite number of steps, nor can its value be given in "closed form" using a finite number of symbols.

So, even though we may argue that there is an uncountable infinite number of real numbers, we can only specify at most a countably infinite subset of real numbers.

I will call those real numbers which are given by an approximating algorithm *specific* real numbers.  Real numbers which are not specifically identified by this means I will call *anonymous* real numbers.

**Assuming that it has been proposed, where has this distinction between *specific* and *anonymous* been proposed before?**

"The Tao that can be told is not the eternal Tao" ~~ Laozi

Comment: Do not add irrelevant tags back, thank you.

Comment: The statement "we can only specify countably many real numbers" is false. This is a very subtle issue, but it is consistent that we can specify *all* the real numbers. Indeed, we might be able to specify *all* the objects of the mathematical universe.

Comment: I clearly explained my reason for including the axiom of choice tag.  If you disagree with my argument, then explain why.

Comment: What you're asking about has nothing to do with the axiom of choice. Even if the axiom of choice fails, the real numbers are still uncountable.

Comment: You have completely missed the meaning of my question.  I am not attempting to refute the concept of uncountability.  I am trying to clarify it.

Comment: The axiom of choice has nothing to do with "uncountable", and "specifying every real number" is consistent, and does not contradict that there are uncountably many real numbers.

Comment: saying so don't make it so.

Comment: Right. But proving so does. And since both of these statements have been proved before, I'm not sure what's your point.

Comment: How is this different from me saying "Let $x$ be a real number". Have I specified it? No. Have I appealed to the axiom of choice? Also no.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  The statement has no more meaning than the statement *Let Zot be a man.*  Until a specific man is identified as having the designation Zot, the assertion is merely hypothetical.

Comment: That's not how mathematical quantification works.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A variable is by definition not a number.  A numerical variable is an abstraction of the concept of number.

Comment: What definition? "Let $x$ be a real number" just assigns $x$ meaning, it is a real number.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By the definition of *variable*.

Comment: It is a *bound variable*.

Comment: It looks pretty free to me, but binding a variable doesn't make it a number.  Binding a variable to a specific value is the only way to legitimately justify calling it a number.  And that is the act of replacing the variable by a number.  Numbers are $1,2,3,1.1,0.\bar{3}, -8, \pi, \text{ etc.}$  Unless you have $x=1$ or $x=\pi$, or etc. $x$ is not a number.

Comment: When you say "Let $x$ be a real number", then $x$ is bound. Not in the sense of being quantified over, but in the sense that it is bound to a certain set. It represents *some* number. In praxis, it means that you have chosen *some* number, and you work with. But it means that the only restriction on this number is that it is a real number. Specifying its actual value is irrelevant. If I say that "$x\in\{0,1,2\}$ implies that $x$ is a natural number", then in particular that means that when $x$ is bound to the set $\{0,1,2\}$, I can guarantee that $x$ is a natural number. No computation needed.

Comment: “Variables are letters that do not refer to any definite entity but rather to a definite range of entities, whose names can be substituted for these variables.” Page 11 Vol I: https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion you are calling “specific real number”, which you are using to mean a number whose digits can be computed by an algorithm, is a notion in mathematics.  The standard term for it is [computable real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).  And as you said, such numbers are countable, because there are only countably many algorithms.

However, computable real numbers do not even exhaust the real numbers which can be unambiguously specified.  That’s because it’s possible to be unambiguously specify an real whose digits cannot be computed by any algorithm, for instance [Chaitin’s constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).  So there is a broader notion of real numbers which can be unambiguously specified.  Those are called [definable real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number), and they too are countable.  Because there are only countably many definitions.

Comment: Definable implicitly mean that you have a fixed structure and language in mind. You can also ask what is the definition of a real number which defines the continuum pattern below $\aleph_\omega$. Is that number "definable"?